# show that if $X\ge 0$ , $E(X)\le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X>n)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

if $X$ is a random variable and also let $X\ge 0$ , I want to show $E(X)\le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X>n)$.

Comment: **Crosspost**: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/77922/2970

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Show $X \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty I_{X > n}$.  Note the right hand side is nothing more than $\text{ceil}(X)$, where "ceil" or "ceiling" means round up to the next integer.

Comment: I try to show  that but i can't. if it possible for you help me in this case.

Comment: Suppose for some point in the probability space we have $m-1 < X(\omega) \le m$.  Then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty I_{X(\omega)>n} = \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} 1$, since $X(\omega)>n$ if and only if $n \le m-1$.  And $\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} 1 = m$.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose the random variable $X$ takes values in $\left\{ 0,1,2,\ldots\right\} $ then:

$$E\left[X\right]=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kP\left\{ X=k\right\} $$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}P\left\{ X=k\right\} $$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}P\left\{ X=k\right\} $$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left\{ X\geq n\right\}$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P\left\{ X>n\right\} $$

So you even have $=$ instead of $\leq$.

Comment: This assumes X is discrete...?

Comment: @BCLC Yes. It assumes that $P(X\in\{0,1,\dots\})=1$ and $\{0,1,\cdots\}$ is a countable set. Did you downvote this? If so then explain why.

Comment: Does it assume such? How do you know?

Comment: @BCLC In the question of the OP it is not assumed if that's what you mean. $I$ am the one that assumes in this answer in order to provide some valuable information ($\leq$ can be switched for $=$ in this situation). *Assuming* does not ask for *knowledge*. You haven't answered my question yet.

Comment: Yes, and I'm sorry I was an ass, drhab