# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n}\lvert X_n\rvert>\varepsilon\right)<\infty$.

Tags: probability-theory

> > Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of identically distributed integrable random variables.

My aim is to show for an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$, that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n}\lvert X_n\rvert>\varepsilon\right)<\infty.
$$

I would like to make it as straightforward as possible.

I started with the following:

I call the probability space $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mathbb{P})$.

Because the $X_n$ are identically distributed it is

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n}\lvert X_n\rvert>\varepsilon\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n}\lvert X_1\rvert>\varepsilon\right).
$$
Then my next step was to write
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n}\lvert X_1\rvert>\varepsilon\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1_{\frac{1}{n}\lvert X_1\rvert>\varepsilon}\right).
$$

But now, I do not know how to continue it a way that makes sense...

Do you have an idea?

With greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you told that $X_n \in L^1$?  Then you can use an argument similar to that given in: [show that if $X\ge 0$ , $E(X)\le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X>n)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583186/show-that-if-x-ge-0-ex-le-sum-n-0-inftypxn)

You will need to prove the opposite inequality, but the argument only needs a slight modification.

Comment: $X_n$ integrable means measurable and $\int_{\Omega}\lvert X_n\rvert\, d\mathbb{P}<\infty$. So $X_n\in\mathfrak{L}^1$, yes. But I do not come along with that link. Sorry.

Comment: Did you mean you do not see how to use the argument given in the link?

Comment: Yes, right. I do not see that.

Comment: I think, I have to show $\lvert X_1\rvert\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1_{\lvert X_1\rvert > n\varepsilon}$, but do not see how to do so.

Comment: You have to show $\varepsilon^{-1}|X_1| \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty I_{|X_1|>n\varepsilon}$.

Comment: OK, I think I got it! I write it here as an answer. May you then have a look on it, please? Post in in some minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion. Please have a look on it.

Define $Y:=\frac{\lvert X_1\rvert}{\varepsilon}$.
$$
A_m:=\left\{\omega\in\Omega: m\leq Y(\omega)<m+1\right\}, m\geq 1.
$$

Consider an arbitrary fixed $\omega\in\Omega$. Then $Y(\omega)\in A_m$ for a $m\geq 1$.

Then it is
$$
Y(\omega)\geq \sum_{n=1}^m 1_{\left\{Y>n\right\}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1_{\left\{Y>n\right\}}.
$$
Because $\omega$ was chosen arbitrarily, this is for any $\omega\in\Omega$.
From this it follows
$$
\Rightarrow\mathbb{E}(Y)\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}(1_{\left\{Y>n\right\}})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\left\{Y>n\right\})
$$
And (because of the integrability of $X_1$) it is
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y)=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{\Omega}\lvert X_1\rvert\, d\mathbb{P}<\infty.
$$

Comment: Yes, it is correct.