# How to prove that $E[|X|]$ is finite iff $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n^2}E[|X|^2I_{|X|\le n}]$ converges

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let a random variables $X$. Show that
$$
E[|X|]<+\infty\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n>1}\dfrac{1}{n^2}E[|X|^2I_{|X|\le n}]<+\infty
$$
where the $I_{|x|\le n}$ is the [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

**My try:** since
$E[|X|]<+\infty$
then we have
$$\int_{R}|X|d P_{X}(x)<+\infty$$
and then I want use this central limit Theorem ,and I can't.

Thank you

Comment: I wouldnt say what you wrote down is exactly a try...

Comment: What is $I_{|X|\leq n}$?

Comment: @Ragnar indicator functions, surely...

Comment: |X| in the second displayed formula should be |x|.

Comment: This "try" is one of the phoniest I have read on the site (which sees many). Central limit theorem? Come on!

Comment: @Did cant agree less, really, and good one about the clt

Comment: @Did and seasonal greetings from a place on the other side of La Manche! Hope you had a good xmas!

Comment: @Lost1 Thanks--and the same to you!

Comment: I think it was a hard question.  The OP was trying his best.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith OK. Replace "and then I want use this central limit Theorem ,and I can't" by "and then I want (to) use a principle of large deviations (but) I can't", does your comment still holds? Replace it by "and then I want to use the classification of finite groups (but) I can't", still the same comment?

Comment: @Did I think the OP genuinely thought that the central limit theorem was the way to go.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith The problem is to fathom how one can sincerely imagine there would be a link between CLT (involving infinite series of $L^2$ random variables) and the question here (involving a unique random variable, not even necessarily $L^2$). Surely you have more imagination than I, because I cannot.

Comment: @Did This is the way I am thinking.  The OP is taking a class in probability theory.  They just covered the CLT in class.  This came a week or two after they covered the SLLN (strong law of large numbers).  The person posing this homework was wanting the student to use techniques from the proof of SLLN.  But the OP was grasping at straws and thinking of the thing he or she just learned a few days ago.

Comment: @Did I admit my reasoning is weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $A_j:=\{\omega, j-1\lt j\leqslant j\}$.

1. Show that "$X$ integrable" is equivalent to $\sum_j j\mu(A_j)$ is convergent.
2. Show that there exists a constant $C$ such that 
   $$\frac 1C\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^j\mathbb E[X^2\chi_{A_j}]\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^\infty j\mu(A_j)\leqslant C\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^j\mathbb E[X^2\chi_{A_j}].$$
3. Conclude.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me btw. Really appreciate it. That post needs to go...

Answer (score 2):

You can use "summation by parts:"
$$
\sum_{n>0}\dfrac{1}{n^2}E[|X|^2I_{|X|\le n}] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^n \dfrac{1}{n^2}E[|X|^2I_{m-1 < |X|\le m}] = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=m}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2} E[|X|^2I_{m-1 < |X|\le m}]
$$
Now approximate:
$$ \sum_{n=m}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2} \approx \frac1m ,$$
and
$$ E[|X|^2I_{m-1 < |X|\le m}] \approx m^2 \Pr(|X| \in (m-1,m]) .$$
Now use the kind of argument shown here: [Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n}\lvert X_n\rvert>\varepsilon\right)<\infty$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619829/show-that-sum-n-1-infty-mathbbp-left-frac1n-lvert-x-n-rvert-varep/619834#619834)

(Notation: when I say $A \approx B$, I mean that $A/B$ and $B/A$ are bounded by universal constants that don't depend upon the parameters used to describe $A$ and $B$.)

Comment: I wish i had a way of hinting like. You did without giving the answer away

Answer (score 1):

Summing up inequalities $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \geq 2$, we see that on the event $\{|X| \geq 2\}$, one has
$$
\tag{$\ast$}
|X| = \frac{|X|^2}{|X|} \leq \sum_{n > 1} \frac{1}{n^2} |X|^2I_{|X| \leq n} = |X|^2\sum_{n \geq |X|} \frac{1}{n^2} \leq \frac{|X|^2}{|X|-1} \leq |X|+2
$$
and of course $E(|X|) < \infty \iff E(|X|I_{|X| \geq 2}) < \infty$.

The result follows by taking expectations in ($\ast$) and using the Fubini-Tonelli theorem.